# [programming-puzzle]: Isn't it obvious?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) tag seems a bit useless given we're called 'Programming Puzzles and Code-Golf'. It seems to be used when no other objective winning criteria is used and sometimes used in conjunction with other winning criteria tags.

15 out of the 29 questions in the tag are closed and of the remaining 14, 7 of them have other criterion that suggest the winner. This leaves a total of 7 valid [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) tags.

I propose we remove the tag from questions with another winning objective tag and on the other questions replace it with [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) or possible add [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle) as a synonym of [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge)

Comment: I think it'd be even better to just take "Programming Puzzles" out of our name, but aside from that, another alternative is to blacklist [tag:programming-puzzle]. It's actually quite normal to blacklist tags that have the site's name in them (i.e., [tag:christianity] on Christianity.SE, or [tag:bicycles] on Bicycles.SE]).

Comment: From the wiki `A programming puzzle includes a goal, a partially completed program, and rules outlining how the program can be modified. The program is specifically designed to make achieving the goal difficult. An answer to a programming puzzle takes the program and modifies it only in ways specified in the rules, so that the goal is achieved.` This is very clearly distinct from code challenge and golf. Just because the latter tends to be easier to do and more popular is no reason to make the former off-topic.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ok then, the tag is horribly misused

Comment: That does seem like a good reason to consider removing the tag where it is misapplied.

Comment: I suspect the name "programming puzzles" is contributing to the misplaced coding help questions where the poster is "puzzled about programming".

Comment: @xnor Then why not tell people to post that on Stack Overflow in the tag info?

Comment: @Peanut If such people read tag info, they would already have read something that tells them that this is a site for coding contests and not programming help.